# Windows 11 - USB C Docking station keeps disconnecting devices

Tags: usb-c, thunderbolt

**Scenario**

I have an Anker Docking Station (model Anker 675) which I bought to help me switching between my personal laptop and the company's laptop without having to connect/disconnect lots of cables daily.

The docking station works perfectly with my company's laptop (Windows 10, full of restrictions). However when I switch to my own laptop things change.

At first everything worked fine for a few minutes and then the keyboard suddenly stopped responding. After a while the keyboard stopped responding at all. I even thought the USB door was gone, but, again, it works fine with my company's laptop.

Since I am always on a rush and have no time to keep solving these "little things", I then started connecting the keyboard directly to my own laptop. However now it is my mouse that starts working fine and then stops suddenly. Disconnecting the USB C docking station does not always work so I started turning it off and on again.

**Things I have tried**

I have searched all over and the common advice is going to Device Manager and run through all USB devices and uncheck "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" in the Power Management tab for that USB device (if such option is available). I did it but it did not work.

My laptop charger is 130W and my docking station delivers up to 100W. I thought that this could be the issue (laptop lacking energy and disconneting devices to manage power). I then started to connect the original charger along with the USB C docking station, but it also did not work.

Since this is starting to have an impact in my productivity I would like to know if someone here can help.

**My specifications**

My laptop is a Dell Inspiron Plus 7620 and it runs Windows 11 Home Edition.

Comment: @John No, you're mistaken. The only available downloads are QSG (hint: It means "quick startup guide") and user's manual. No drivers are require for this kind of docks. The only similar devices that do need drivers are the ones that include DisplayLink chipsets. Commenting just for the sake of it in areas you don't understand is quite unhelpful.

Comment: Site says drivers are there - Why am I mistaken ?  But if there are no drivers then the dock is not going to work.

Comment: Found this thread on Google, sadly looking for the same answers. Rather than adding a 'me too', I can make it more interesting: I am using a Lenovo L15 with a Dell D6000 docking station. At the office at least 3 other people had the same issue in one day, and we use a mix of HP and Lenovo docking stations there. This seems to be a Windows 11 thing, unrelated to dock or laptop model.